# Problem with winsock recv() and accept()

Tags: c++, sockets, winsock

I'm having trouble with a socket application I'm programming in C++.  I'm doing my programming with Bloodshed Dev-Cpp on Windows XP.  I made a class for handling all the message transfers and have a client and server program that both use that class for handling their services.  The application itself is very basic, the only intent I have for it is to get all this to work.

The client, which is for sending messages, works like I expect it to.  If my server is running, it doesn't have any errors when sending a message.  If it's not running it'll pass an error.  But my server continuously accepts weird gibberish.  It's always the same data.  When it receives the  message there is no effect.  If I have my client try to identify the server, it gets back gibberish.

I have included my source code here.  The linker also brings in two extra parameters: -lwsock32 and an inclusion of the library libws2_32.a, which came with Dev-Cpp.

Here's the header for my Messager class:

```
#ifndef MESSAGER
#define MESSAGER

#include <string>

class Messager{
    private:
        int sendSocket;
        int listenSocket;

    public:
        void init(void);
        bool connect(std::string ip, std::string port);
        bool bind(std::string port);
        void listen(void);
        void send(std::string message);
        std::string receive(void);
};
#endif
```

These are my definitions for the Messager class:

```
#include "Messager.h"
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <windows.h>

void Messager::init(void){
    WSADATA wsaData;

    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(1,1), &wsaData);
}

bool Messager::connect(std::string ip, std::string port){
    struct addrinfo hints;
    struct addrinfo *res;
    bool success = false;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    getaddrinfo(ip.c_str(), port.c_str(), &hints, &res);

    sendSocket = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);

    success = ::connect(sendSocket, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen) != -1;

    freeaddrinfo(res);

    return success;
}

bool Messager::bind(std::string port){
    struct addrinfo hints, *res;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    getaddrinfo(NULL, port.c_str(), &hints, &res);

    listenSocket = socket(res->ai_family, res->ai_socktype, res->ai_protocol);

    if(listenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET){
        return false;
    }

    if(::bind(listenSocket, res->ai_addr, res->ai_addrlen) == -1){
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

void Messager::listen(void){
    ::listen(listenSocket, 10);
}

int Messager::send(std::string message){
    const std::string terminator = "\r\n";
    std::string realMessage;
    int size = 0;
    int totalSent = 0;

    realMessage = message;
    realMessage += terminator;

    size = realMessage.size();

    totalSent = ::send(sendSocket, realMessage.c_str(), size, 0);

    if(totalSent == 0 || totalSent == -1){
        return 0; // There must be an error, 0 means it is an error
    }

    // This statement keeps adding the results of ::send to totalSent until it's the size of the full message
    for(totalSent = 0; totalSent < size; totalSent += ::send(sendSocket, realMessage.c_str(), size, 0));

    return totalSent;
}

// This function has been updated a lot thanks to @Luke
std::string Messager::receive(void){
    const int bufferSize = 256;
    const std::string terminator = "\r\n";
    char buffer[bufferSize];
    int i = 0;
    int received = 0;
    std::string tempString;
    size_t term = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++){
        buffer[i] = 0;
    }

    received = ::recv(listenSocket, buffer, bufferSize, 0);
    tempString = buffer;
    term = tempString.find(terminator);

    if(term != -1){ // Already have line
        line = tempString;
    }

    while(received != -1 && received != 0){ // While it is receiving information...
        // Flush the buffer
        for(i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++){
            buffer[i] = 0;
        }

        ::recv(listenSocket, buffer, bufferSize, 0);
        tempString += buffer;
        term = tempString.find(terminator);

        if(term != -1){ // Found terminator!
            return tempString;
        }
    }

    throw 0; // Didn't receive any information.  Throw an error
}
```

Any ideas about what might be going on would be really appreciated.  If necessary I can post the code the server and client use, but I can give a general outline:

Server:

- messager.init()
- messager.bind()
- messager.listen()
- messager.receive() <-- includes accept()

Client:

- messager.init()
- messager.connect()
- messager.send()

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I see two concerns.

1. You can't safely use the string assignment operator in Message::receive().  The assignment operator relies on the character array being NULL-terminated, and in this case it is not.  It's probably filling it up with a bunch of garbage data.  You should get the number of characters actually received (i.e. the return value of recv()) and use the string::assign() method to fill the string object.
2. There is no code to ensure all the data has been sent or received.  recv() is going to return as soon as any data is available; you really need to loop until you have received the entire message.  For plain-text data, typically people use a CR-LF pair to indicate the end of a line.  You keep calling recv() and buffering the results until you see that CR-LF pair and then return that line to the caller.  You should also loop on send() until your entire buffer has been sent.

Typically this looks something like the following (this is all from memory so there are probably a few minor errors, but this is the gist of it):

```
bool Message::Receive(std::string& line)
{
    // look for the terminating pair in the buffer
    size_t term = m_buffer.find("\r\n");
    if(term != -1)
    {
        // already have a line in the buffer
        line.assign(m_buffer, 0, term); // copy the line from the buffer
        m_buffer.erase(0, term + 2); // remove the line from the buffer
        return true;
    }
    // no terminating pair in the buffer; receive some data over the wire
    char tmp[256];
    int count = recv(m_socket, tmp, 256);
    while(count != -1 && count != 0)
    {
        // successfully received some data; buffer it
        m_buffer.append(tmp, count);
        // see if there is now a terminating pair in the buffer
        term = m_buffer.find("\r\n");
        if(term != -1)
        {
            // we now have a line in the buffer
            line.assign(m_buffer, 0, term); // copy the line from the buffer
            m_buffer.erase(0, term + 2); // remove the line from the buffer
            return true;
        }
        // we still don't have a line in the buffer; receive some more data
        count = recv(m_socket, tmp, 256);
    }
    // failed to receive data; return failure
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I see.  Thank you that'll probably help things a lot.  I thought the buffer would be filled with garbage because it wasn't initialized, but at the moment I just wanted it to return what I wanted, so I was going to fix that but thanks.  But I think that problem you said with send() and recv() splitting the messages is the source of all this, probably.  Thank you very much, this is probably the answer.

Comment: There was a problem caused by that, but the original problem still remains.  It turns out send wasn't sending everything I wanted to and, as you can look at above now, I have fixed that problem.  Thank you, @Luke.  But recv() is still getting strange gibberish and I don't know why.  send() shows it can connect and send a message with a problem, and the sockets are valid, but recv() still gets gibberish.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be a bit concerned about your `receive` code. It creates a `char*` buffer to receive the data but doesn't actually allocate any memory for it.

Now I can't tell whether you're calling the WinSock `recv` there since you don't explicitly say `::recv` but I think you would need to either:

- allocate some space with `malloc` first (id `recv` wants a buffer); or
- pass the address of the buffer pointer (if `recv` allocates its own buffer).

I'm actually surprised that the doesn't cause a core dump since the value of `buffer` could be set to *anything* when you call `recv`.

Something like this may be better:

```
char *Messager::receive(void){
    int newSocket = 0;
    struct sockaddr_storage *senderAddress;
    socklen_t addressSize;
    char *buffer;

    addressSize = sizeof senderAddress;
    newSocket = accept(listenSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&senderAddress,
        &addressSize);

    buffer = new char[20];
    recv(newSocket, buffer, 20, 0);

    return buffer;
```

}

But you need to remember that the client of this function is responsible for freeing the buffer when it's finished with it.

Comment: I was worried about that.  I tried making an array of chars, 100 or so elements to try to give the buffer room, but the problem remained.  I'll test it again and edit the code to make sure that's not part of the problem at all.

Comment: I just tested to make sure and I got the same results.  I'll keep it as an array to be safe.  Thanks for the input.

Comment: You can't make it a char array since that doesn't survive function exit - it will be destroyed when the function exits and the pointer you return will point to rubbish. You need to malloc the data area.

Comment: I've never used `malloc` but I'll try it.  Don't arrays allocate memory, though?  I thought I'd be safe with that.  If I passed a pointer to the buffer it would be getting a char**, since an array is a char* allocated with however many elements you determine... or am I wrong?  Either way I'll try it.

Comment: Oh!  I see what you mean.  That's why I passed it back as std::string.  And also, that is ::recv.  I'll label it to be more explicit.

Comment: @alecRN, you want to allocate the memory on the heap, as opposed to the stack.  @paxdiablo is saying that when you just say `char buf[100];` that's a stack allocation, and it'll go away when `receive` returns.  If you use `malloc` to allocate on the heap, you can pass the pointer around and it's all gravy. :)

Comment: What I was thinking was std::string supports copying a char*, so it has a lifetime of its own and doesn't depend on the pointer you copied from.  I knew buffer would go away when the function returned, which is why the return type is std::string, which forces the char* to copy on std::string's terms, so it copies safely.  I believe that's how it works, and I'm pretty certain I've returned a char* as std::string and been able to keep the information.  Perhaps the problem is I'm not being very explicit?  Or is it true that a std::string does not copy things to itself?

Comment: I tested it with std::cout inside and outside the function to see if there was any loss and there wasn't.  But I think trying to pass the char* back and attempt to implicitly copy it into the string won't work, like you pointed out.  I probably just got lucky.  Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: An explicit "return new std::string(buffer);" may work if you want to go that way.

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions:

- check the return values of all the socket functions  you call
- ditch DevC++ - it is buggy as hell & is no longer being developed - use http://www.codeblocks.org/ instead.

Comment: You mean like check if `socket == SOCKET_INVALID` (or something to that effect)?  Could work, I'll try it.

What's buggy about it, the compiler or IDE?  But code blocks would be good if it has a more updated library and such.  I'll try it, thanks.

Comment: I'd give some serious thought to just downloading Microsoft's Visual Studio Express. It's free (beer-free rather than speech-free) and is much better supported.

Comment: I've tried it but I don't like it very much.  Maybe because it feels like behind my back its going to make it rely on .dll's and other things I don't expect it to.  I could be wrong though.

Comment: @alecRN Re the library version, you should really track GCC rather than a specific IDE. My facourite GCC supplier for Windows is Twilight Dragon at http://tdragon.net/recentgcc - it's a MinGW branch.

Answer (score 0):

In your `receive` function, the `buffer` local is never initialized to anything, so you end up reading your message into some random memory and probably causing corruption or crashing.  You probably want `char buffer[MAX_MSG_LENGTH];` instead of `char *buffer`

Comment: That won't actually work, @Chris, since the buffer won't be ther when the function exits. A malloc will be required.

Comment: Should be fine, as the buffer is just used to initialize a string (which is returned), and can go away after that